# Roots of bessel function of first kind for negative n in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

There are some codes which compute the roots of

```
J_n(x),    n > 0
```

I want to calculate the roots of:

```
J_n(x),    n < 0
```

`n` is a real number.

Is there some algorithm or yet better some Matlab code which does this.

Comment: Have you tried `fzero`? How many of the roots do you want? What particular values/range of `n`?

Comment: If n is restricted to the Integers, the functions have the same roots since they're linear dependent to a factor of (-1)^n.

Answer (score 0):

In [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704279190169K) there is an algorithm to calculate the `N` first roots of Bessel function of the first kind. This works only if `n > -1` in `J_n(x)`.

The whole root calculation turns into an eigenvalue problem. The estimated errors have been calculated in the paper.